# Upload multiple images in php

Tags: php, html, forms, post

i am creating a page called events i have created a form which submits on post file, this is my form code, `
                Adding Staff

```
            <div class="box">
                <label>Heading</label>
                <input type="text" name="heading" id="heading"/>
            </div>


            <div class="box" style="margin-left: 120px">
                <label>Description 1</label>
                <textarea cols="30" rows="5" name="description_1" id="description_1"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <label>Description 2</label>
                <textarea cols="30" rows="5" name="description_2" id="description_2"></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="box">
                <label>Upload Images</label>
                <input type="file" name="picture" id="picture"/>
                <label>Is Rename <input type="checkbox" name="is_rename"> </label>
            </div>

            <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="box" style="width: 100px; margin-left: 350px;">
                <input style="padding: 4px" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
            </div>`
```

This is my post

```
    <?php
ob_start();
session_start();
include_once "../../classes/addClasses.php";
$heading = $_POST['heading'];
$description_1 = $_POST['description_1'];
$description_2 = $_POST['description_2'];
$picture = $_POST['picture'];
$target_dir = "../../../uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["picture"]["name"]);
print_r($_FILES);

if( isset( $_POST['is_rename'] ) )
    $file_name = time().'-'.basename($_FILES["picture"]["name"]);
else
    $file_name = basename($_FILES["picture"]["name"]);
if(empty($_FILES['picture']['name'])){
    echo "please select a file to upload";
    ?>
    <script>window.location.href="http://localhost/learner-pack/admin/admin/add_events.php?error=empty"</script>
    <?php
}
$target_file = $target_dir . $file_name;
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["picture"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["picture"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file '".$file_name."' already exists.";
}elseif (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["picture"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file " . $file_name . " has been uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
/*$created_by = $_POST['created_by'];
$updated_by = $_POST['updated_by'];
$current_date = $_POST['current_date'];
$updated_date = $_POST['updated_date'];
$visitor_counter = $_POST['visitor_counter'];*/

if($admin->addingEvents($heading,$description_1,$description_2, $file_name))
{
    header('Location: ../view_events.php?added=true');
}
else
{
    echo "Error";
}
?>
```

please help me to store multiple images in table using one field and retireve them to view on events page when i fetch one row so that all images on that row are fetchable

Comment: You're supposed to first do some research on your problem and when you could not find any solution online, then post your question here. you have to add a `multiple attribute` to your `<input type="file" ...>` tag and then in your `php` code you can have to `loop` through the `$_FILES array`. [this link](http://www.code-hound.com/upload-multiple-files-at-once-with-jquery-and-php/) may help you.

Comment: try using a plugin https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload